# How to find and restore deleted items?

Tags: targetprocess

We have converted a user story into a task. And all tasks of this user story has been automatically deleted.

How to restore these tasks?

I dont found something on this subject in documentation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

At the time of writing this answer, there is no ability yet to restore items from the UI.

However, they have an idea to implement it in future: 

[Undo / Undelete action / Ability to retrieve / restore deleted entities / Improved History Audit / Recycle bin](https://tp3.uservoice.com/forums/174654-we-will-rock-you/suggestions/3130865-undo-undelete-action-ability-to-retrieve-res:d9S-pcMCfinYF9CBnwg0oGErUgw)

For now you can contact support@targetprocess.com, and they are able to restore / fix / reassign the deleted tickets for you.